# While renaming file in VBA, adding increment number for unique name

Tags: excel, vba

While running the script for more files, if it found the same name then it adds an incrementing number for the duplicate name at the end, but then it adds the increment number even for some unique name also, not for all unique name.

What goes wrong here?

Here is the image for your ref. In the image, I have hidden some parts of the file name for privacy.
[File Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNWvN.png)

```
Option Explicit
Sub RenameAllFilesInFolder()

    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String, fName As String
    Dim MyFilePatNm As String
    Dim owbk As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim v As String, fv As String, chkFile As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFileExists As String
    Dim fnum As Integer

    MyFolder = "E:\SC_SS\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*size*.xls")
     

    Do Until MyFile = ""
     
        MyFilePatNm = MyFolder & MyFile
        
         Set owbk = Workbooks.Open(MyFilePatNm)
        
                Set ws = owbk.Sheets(1)
                 v = "SS_" & ws.[C3].Value
                 chkFile = v & ".xls"
                strFileName = MyFolder & chkFile
               strFileExists = Dir(strFileName)
                Do While strFileExists <> ""
                    fnum = fnum + 1
                    strFileExists = Dir(MyFolder & v & " " & fnum & ".xls")
                Loop
             
                If fnum > 0 Then
                    fv = v & " " & fnum & ".xls"
                Else
                    fv = v & ".xls"
                End If
                fName = MyFolder & fv
                ws.SaveAs Filename:=fName, FileFormat:=xlExcel8, CreateBackup:=False
                Windows(fv).Close False
                Kill MyFilePatNm
        MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*size*.xls")
    Loop
       
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you reset fnum to 0, so every files found after the one already existing will have the index fnum added.

Comment: @VincentG Thank you very much for pointing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the job done, with setting fnum to zero in below.

```
If fnum > 0 Then
  fv = v & " " & fnum & ".xls"
Else
  fv = v & ".xls"
End If

fnum = 0
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.